# Even after Adding Form Key in phtml Magento 2.3 shows invalid form key error often

Tags: magento2.3, error, form-key

I added Form key in all forms. But in some forms still, I am getting Invalid form key Please refresh error often. How to solve this? Is I need to add further things to solve this? Kindly help me.

Comment: could you please share the code on which you getting this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I got Cannot read property 'sectionLoadUrl' of undefined in that form. That displayed Invalid form key Please refresh error often.

I fixed it by adding the following code to layout.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block name="customer.section.config" class="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig"
               template="Magento_Customer::js/section-config.phtml"/>
        <block name="customer.customer.data"
               class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
               template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```